# Seaborn heatmap xticklabels horizontalalignment not working when ticklabels on top

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to create a Seaborn Heatmap with the xticklabels along the top (to try and emulate an Excel table with conditional formatting).

The code I am using is as follows:

```
plt.figure(figsize=[12, 6])
ax = sns.heatmap(df, vmin=1, vmax=149, cmap=cmap_RdYlGn_r, cbar=False, fmt='s')

# Each pair of columns is a rank / value. Hide the label for one of these
ticklbls = ax.get_xticklabels(which='both')
for x in ticklbls:
    x.set_ha='left' #### This has no effect
    if '[raw value]' in x.get_text():
        x.set_text('')
    elif '[rank]' in x.get_text():
        x.set_text('\n'.join(wrap(x.get_text(), 30)))
ax.set_xticklabels(ticklbls)

# Put the xticklabels at the top of the heatmap
ax.tick_params(axis='x', top=False, labeltop=True, labelbottom=False, direction='out')
```

How can I get the xticklabels to be left aligned over each column (rather than centre aligned)? The `x.set_ha='left'` in my for loop seems to have no effect.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `set_ha` is a function. You need to **call** it with the argument of 'left'.

You also need to set the alignment after you move the tick labels to the top of the heatmap:

```
# Put the xticklabels at the top of the heatmap
ax.tick_params(axis='x', top=False, labeltop=True, labelbottom=False, direction='out')

ticklbls = ax.get_xticklabels(which='both')

for x in ticklbls:
    x.set_ha('left')
```